# Docusign RequestRecipientToken no longer working

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Docusign SOAP API for signing the documents. When using the RequestRecipientToken method, it returns the URL for signing the document, but it was no longer working and it asks docusign username and password.

How can I get a URL that will used in anytime and will do auto signing?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately your question is a little broad and non specific. Can you please rephrase so that you are asking a specific, clear and answerable programming related question?

Answer (score 1):

Typically if you want to bypass the login screen you'll either want to turn off the signer login requirement, or use an embedded signing session.

When creating the envelope, specify a clientUserId for the recipient. Then when you make the POST call to retrieve the recipient view, if you include that ID a URL will be sent back that will allow them to click and access their envelope without having to authenticate.

These URLs do expire after 5 minutes, so you can't really have a static link that works at all times.

DocuSign also does not support automatic signing, as the manual signing process is part of what validates an envelopes audit trail.